# Use FFMpeg libraries to read an audio file while it is being generated

Tags: ffmpeg

I got an audio engine, which generates aac files. I want to mux this audio with some video. I'm using ffmpeg libraries to do just that - meaning, after the audio file is ready, I read it and mux it.
Now - for performance reasons, I don't want to wait until the audio engine completes the audio generation, I want the muxer to start reading the audio while it is being generated.
Can I achieve that using the FFMpeg libraries?
Which approach should I take?
Couldn't find any examples doing that